# PHP: Check if current URL is part of defined URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to check of the current URL is part of a pre-defined URL.

For example: I want to check if the domain `example.com/shop/` is part of the viewed URL.

I'm using the following function to get the current URL and a pre-defined (`$shop_page_url`) URL:

```
function shop_page_url_condition(){
    global $wp;
    $shop_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
    $shop_page_url = get_permalink($shop_page_id );
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request).'/');
    if( $shop_page_url == $current_url) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this case it only works if the `$shop_page_url` is the same as the `$current_url`.

But I want to check if pre-defined URL (`$shop_page_url`) is part of the current URL (`example.com/shop/page/7`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) what you're looking for?

If I'm understanding correctly, you would just want to see if it returns false:

```
if ( strpos( $current_url, $shop_page_url ) !== false ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

You could also simplify the above if you wanted to save a few lines of code:

```
return strpos( $current_url, $shop_page_url ) !== false;
```

`strpos() >= 0` won't work. If the substring is not found at all, doing that will end up returning `true`, which is not what you'd want here!